# Improve efficiency for ranking in Bag of words model

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am creating a text summarizer and using a basic model to work with using Bag of words approach.
the code i am performing is using the nltk library. 
the file read is a large file with over 2500000 words. 
below is the loop i am working on with but this takes over 2 hours to run and complete. is there a way to optimize this code

```
f= open('Complaints.csv', 'r')
raw = f.read()
len(raw)
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
len(tokens)
freq = nltk.FreqDist(text)
top_words = [] # blank dictionary 
top_words = freq.most_common(100)
print(top_words)
sentences = sent_tokenize(raw)
print(raw)
ranking = defaultdict(int)
for i, sent in enumerate(raw):
for word in word_tokenize(sent.lower()):
    if word in freq:
        ranking[i]+=freq[word]
top_sentences = nlargest(10, ranking, ranking.get)
print(top_sentences)
```

This is only one one file and the actual deployment has more than 10-15 files of similar size. 
How we can improve this.
Please note these are the text from a chat bot and are actual sentences hence there was no requirement to remove whitespaces, stemming and other text pre processing methods

Comment: Is the code in your question actually the code you run? How is `sentences` used? What about `tokens` (For which you fully tokenize the source file)? Do you really use `enumerate(raw)` and not `enumerate(sentences)`? Are you really using `print(raw)` which prints the full source file to console? Please edit your code into a [mre] that you have run and that anyone could run without having to add or edit anything - also please fix your indents.

Comment: I had to stop this code as it was continuously running and never ending. The idea was to take a data frame file and which i had created as raw and find the top 10 occuring sentences.will take to take another approach to get text rank using a very basic algorithm as the client does not provide any GPU and TPU based machines and the code cannot be kept on a cloud environment

Comment: But still, the client will have a multicore cpu, so independent from the implementation, you need to parallelize your code. How can you estimate your code to run two hours if it loops infinitvely?

Comment: I agree, @CLpragmatics - this all sounds horribly vague - and the posted code is strange, hence the vote to close. And ‘is the code in your question atually the code you run?’ hasn’t been answered.

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `if word in top_words:` rather than `if words in freq`? But you didn’t answer whether this is the actual code you run...

Comment: Yes that was the actual code that i had run.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you open at once a large file that needs to fit into your RAM. If you do not have a really good computer, this might be the first bottleneck for perfomance. Read each line separately, or try to use some IO buffer.
What CPU do you have? If you have enough cores, you can get a lot of extra performance when parallelizing the program with an async Pool from Multiprocessing library because you really use the full power of all cores (choose the number of processes according to the thread number. With this method, I reduced a model on 2500 data sets from ~5 minutes to ~17 seconds on 12 threads). You would have to implement the processes to return a dict each, updating them after the processes have finished.

Otherwise, there are machine learning approches for text summarization (sequence to sequence RNNs). With a tensorflow implementation, you can use a dedicated GPU on your local machine (even a decent 10xx or a 2060 from Nvidia will help) to speed up your model.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.06023

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Use google colab, it provides it own GPU

Comment: colab cannot work as this is some sensitive data and cannot be open source cloud